# Creating a cron in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, sticky, posts

I am working to make a cron in wordpress that will remove the sticky option from stick post that have a past due custom expire date. I have everything going except I can't get Wordpress to recognize my cron. Here is my code for my cron within my plugin

```
// Custom Cron Recurrences
function expire_posts_cron_recurrence( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
        'display' => __( 'every three minutes', 'textdomain' ),
        'interval' => 180,
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'expire_posts_cron_recurrence' );

// Schedule Cron Job Event
function expire_posts_cron() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'expire_action_func' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_three_minutes', 'expire_action_func' );
    }
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'expire_posts_cron');

// Scheduled Action Hook
function expire_action( ) {
    // get sticky posts from DB
    $sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
    // check if there are any
    if (!empty($sticky)) {


        $args = array(
            'post__in' => $sticky
        );

        query_posts($args);

        if ( have_posts() ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post(); 
                $post_ID = get_the_ID();

                $expire_date = get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'expires_date', true );
                $expire_time = get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'expires_time', true );

                if(!empty($expire_date) && $expire_date != '' && !empty($expire_time) && $expire_time != ''){
                    $full_datetime = $expire_date.$expire_time." GMT-4:00 DST";
                    $epoch_full_datetime = strtotime($full_datetime);
                    $current_epoch_time = time();
                    if($epoch_full_datetime <= $current_epoch_time){
                        unstick_post( $post_id );
                    }
                }

            } // end while
        } // end if

    }
}

add_action( 'expire_action_func', 'expire_action' );
```

I am printing out the cron jobs in Wordpress with this but my cron isn't there.

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r( _get_cron_array() ); echo '</pre>'; ?>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?